# UItableviewcell with muliple labels and custom height

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have added multiple labels in My Tableview cell. I am displaying facebook message and sender name and photos.For some posts it might be possible that message is unavailable or photo is unavailable .. I checking null condition and if there is no value present I am not creating label for that particular cell... now some label has large string , some may have small.. I am confused with cell's height ,, I am able to get dynamic height for 1 label like this in example [dynamic height](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/) but how can I manage Height according to number of label's text... my code is like

```
    if ([(Facebook * )[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]sender]!= nil) {
    labelSender = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(image_view.frame.size.width+20, 20, 120, 20) ];



    labelSender.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[(Facebook * )[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]sender]];

    [labelSender setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    [labelSender setNumberOfLines:0];

    labelSender.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:59/255.0 green:89/255.0 blue:153/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    labelSender.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15.0];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:labelSender];


    [labelSender release];

    }


if ([(Facebook * )[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]post]!= nil) {


        NSLog(@"post is ==%@",[(Facebook * )[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]post]);

        labelMessage = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(image_view.frame.size.width+20, labelSender.frame.size.height + 20, 200, 20)];

        labelMessage.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[(Facebook * )[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]post]];

        [labelMessage setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        [labelMessage setNumberOfLines:0];

        labelMessage.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

        labelMessage.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13.0];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:labelMessage];

        [labelMessage release]; 

    }
```

please help

Comment: I am unable to get your question... :P

Comment: I want to calculate height for all the labels and their sum of height would be expected height of table

Comment: table ma be of dynamic height?

Comment: So why don't you add your text to different cells, and let the `UITableView` done else for you?

Comment: You have seen facebook Post. just imagine that all post are in tableview's cell. And I have to manage labels for sender name , message ,link ,description ,image..Now is it clear now.??

Comment: Not completely, one comment with all it's stuff will be in one cell?

Comment: one cell is for one message along with its sender name , profile pic, link ,  name , description all this..and may be first description is larger and rest other are short, and also some cell may not contain description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel its better to go for UITextView whenever handling dynamic content.

Comment: I want to only display sender name , message , link... this all are individual

Comment: Only for message keep UITextField. For rest UILabel will do the job. For name label one line, for link label 2 line, and for message keep uitextview. Add all these default value and return it to delegate.

Comment: But label's width could be different .. In that case some of my text will be miss..I have done with one label but confused about 2 or more

Comment: Set some width that is possible in your case. And set UILabels **adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth** property.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the displayed labels in an `NSMutableArray` that is a property of the cell. That way you can iterate through simply by using:

```
for (UILabel *tmpLabel in yourLabelArray){
   // do: add height to sum
}
```

This will save you an the if (labelExists) for every label.

Good luck!